# Blue eyes white dragon

Tags: names, participial-phrases

Why  BLUE EYES  white dragon ,not BLUE EYED ? 
Does anyone know why ? 
Because , as far as I’m concerned , the latter is the correct form
Or maybe I just got it wrong? 
 if anyone in this world knows the answer to that , please write back ASAP
I am so so confused 
Or maybe it’s just not about grammar at all ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Blue eyed girl vs Blue eye girl](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/397335/blue-eyed-girl-vs-blue-eye-girl)

Comment: You’ll need to provide more context for the community to match the phrasing to the intent.

Comment: Probably for the same reason that Frank Sinatra was known as "Old Blue Eyes" and not "Old Blue Eyed": it's a nickname based on a striking physical feature, not  an adjectival modifier of a following noun.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Yugioh Fandom page on [Blue-Eyes White Dragon](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Blue-Eyes_White_Dragon_(character)), the character is a White Dragon named Blue-Eyes.

> Despite being always called "Blue-Eyes White Dragon", or even simply
>   just the "White Dragon", Blue-Eyes always has a light blue body as
>   well as blue eyes.

Answer (score 0):

You would use the adjective formed from the past participle of the body part cast as a verb.

> long-legged bird
>
> pigeon-footed runner
>
> blue-eyed dragon
>
> long-eared rabbit
>
> long-haired dog
>
> saber-toothed tiger
>
> double-edged sword

and so forth.

This form will always be grammatical. In some cases, e.g. saber-tooth tiger and double-edge sword, you will hear the adjective being formed from two nouns in combination. This could be a case of the 'd' being dropped for phonetic simplicity, since it tends to happen where the resulting consonant cluster is a little hard to pronounce.  We wouldn't say "a brown-eye girl".

If the question is specifically about a particular playing card of some kind, and not about the grammar of adjectives involving a body-part or attribute,  then some other rule may be in effect.

Comment: Thank you guys so very much. You’ve really helped me with this one